# I can't install Ubuntu, and the installation closes

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation

I'm having a problem with my Ubuntu 16.04 installation, when I try to select a partition it says "No root file system is defined" I also have the New Partition Tablle and Revert buttons disabled, and any time I click the "+ , - or change.." the installation closes. Btw, I have no other OS in my pc.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgbqP.png)

Comment: Is the disk setting in your BIOS set to RAID?